# How do packages that let you control other software work? What are limitations with such an approach?

Tags: api, automation

I was recently using a python package called OpenPyXl. It's a package that let me control and write to Excel and I'm trying to understand how something like that even works. How can Python and Excel "talk" to each other? I had a few questions regrading this topic, I hadn't been able to find definitive answers to.

1. From what I understand after reading a bit, Python must be talking to Excel through some API that the developer (in this case Microsoft I guess) made available for use. Is that generally how software which controls/interacts with other software works?
2. Without an API are you generally unable to interact with software through your own code? Let's say I wanted to write a program that could play the game solitaire on my windows machine, without Microsoft creating a specific API that makes it possible so some code I write can "talk" to Solitaire, would my only option be some sort of program that attempts to actually visually read and comprehend my screen, and control the mouse to implement moves?

I'm just trying to understand how various pieces of software can interact with each other, thus far my only experience has really only been in self contained scripts, and I don't fully understand if every program has some sort of.

If for instance, I had to write a bot to play solitaire, I don't even know where I would begin, and I just want to have a better understanding of how the pieces fit together.

Comment: Note that most (all?) Microsoft Office documents are really just a zip file of XML files (along other things). It could be "talking" to Excel to help it, but it could very well just be unzipping  the document and parsing the files manually.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that's really interesting, I don't know actually what an XML is. I've heard of it, but it always seemed like something kind of advanced and I never looked too much into it. I'll look into a bit more. I was wondering though, broadly speaking am I in the right ballpark? That without an API, one piece of code can't necessarily communicate with another piece of code?

Comment: XML is just structured data. It's similar to HTML. And they are likely just parsing the document themselves. They could also be using a underlying Microsoft-supplied library to do the processing. I don't have enough experience in this area to say for sure.